# Хранение большого объема данных в спортивном программирование (256Mб). Java

Tags: java, память, outofmemoryerror

Я решаю задачу заочного этапа МОШа. Там ограничение по памяти 256Мб ( предполагается, что корректные решения столько используют), я использую около 100Мб , но тестирующая система пишет "Ошибка во время выполнения программы".
Сама программа несложная, но в ней надо хранить 4*10^10 чисел типа Byte. Без этого никуда.
При ручном тестировании я получаю ошибку:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Как я понял, максимум-64Мб, но надо больше, как расширить память, использующуюся программой?

Comment: 4*10^10 -- вы имеете в виду 4e10 байт? Это 40 гигабайт, даже если использовать `byte` вместо `Byte` и не считать накладных расходов. Как вы собираетесь хранить 40 ГБ данных в 100 МБ памяти? Или я чего-то не понял? Может, вам какой-то другой подход найти, чтобы не хранить эти данные? А доступную память можно менять ключами команды `java`:  `java -Xmx1024m MyClass`

Comment: Попытайтесь использовать паттерн легковес, заменяя повторяющуюся структуру данных в отдельные объекты, а эти объекты в хранилище.

Comment: Если это олимпиадная задача, то паттерны там не нужны, а ТС решает её неправильно. Нужна либо какая-то более хитрая структура данных, либо более хитрый алгоритм. Если бы ТС предоставил текст задачи, можно было бы говорить более предметно.

Comment: Неправильно посчитал, там поменьше выйдет.  Куда ввести java: java -Xmx1024m MyClass? Спасибо. Пользуюсь Eclipse Oxygen.